# Type erasure with function pointers does not work with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, type-erasure

I am trying a sort of type-erasure with some function pointers and templates as given in the example below. What I find strange is with GCC i get wrong result where as with VS 2017, I get the expected one. So, who is correct and who is wrong and why ?

Live example on COLIRU: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/225db5711c07c8b0

```
struct A { void PrintA() { std::cout << "Event A" << std::endl; } };
struct B { void PrintB() { std::cout << "Event B" << std::endl; } };
struct C { void PrintC() { std::cout << "Event C" << std::endl; } };

struct RunBase
{
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};


template <typename T>
struct Run : public RunBase
{
    using FUNC = void (T::*)();
    Run(T& o, FUNC&& f) : mObj(o), mFunc(f) {}
    void operator()() override { (mObj.*mFunc)(); }

    T& mObj;
    FUNC& mFunc;
};

int main()
{
    A a; 
    B b; 
    C c; 

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RunBase> > mFuncs;
    mFuncs.push_back(std::make_unique<Run<A> >(a, &A::PrintA));
    mFuncs.push_back(std::make_unique<Run<B> >(b, &B::PrintB));
    mFuncs.push_back(std::make_unique<Run<C> >(c, &C::PrintC));

    for (auto& i : mFuncs)
        (*i)();

  return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

```
Event A
Event B
Event C
```

But GCC gives me:

```
Event C
Event C
Event C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you store a reference inside your object, but `&A::PrintA` etc. are temporaries which are destroyed at the end of the full expression, and so the member reference is left dangling, and its use results in undefined behaviour.

Simply store a copy of the member function pointer to fix it:

```
FUNC mFunc;
```

---

PS. When `mFuncs` is destroyed, the unique pointers delete child objects through a base pointer. The behaviour is undefined unless you declare `RunBase::~RunBase` virtual.

---

> So, who is correct and who is wrong and why ?

Your program is wrong; There is no correct behaviour for it.